# Add MapIcon to MapControl in Universal app using Caliburn Micro

Tags: c#, maps, caliburn.micro, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

Using Caliburn.Micro I'm building an Universal Windows phone app (8.1). 
On a page I intend to show a map with a mapicon position in the center.

```
<Maps:MapControl
      MapServiceToken="XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
      Height="560" Center="{Binding MapCenter}" ZoomLevel="15"
      Margin="0,0,0,0" />
</Maps:MapControl>
```

This works well, but I don't know how to add an MapIcon to the map.
MSDN shows how to add MapIcons from code behind like this:

```
private void AddMapIcon()
{
        MapIcon MapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
        MapIcon1.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = 47.620, Longitude = -122.349 });
        MapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(1.0, 0.5);
        MapIcon1.Title = "Space Needle";
        MapControl1.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn642089.aspx

How do I do this with Caliburn Mirco?

Comment: You might try something do with OnViewReady(object view) override to get a working object of type mapcontrol then you could work outward from there.

Comment: What do you mean "With Caliburn Micro"?